# Django - Standalone - Como validar valor recebido de um campo foreign key?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Django cujo intuito é aproveitar o models tanto para os formulários e views do frontend quanto para um serviço a parte.
Para isso encontrei uma maneira de transformar/usar o models do Django com todo seu ORM de modo standalone, ou seja, sem a necessidade de ter um servidor Django rodando.

Tenho o seguinte model "AgenteDa":

```
from django.db import models
from user.admin import User
        
class AgenteDa (models.Model):
    id_agentes_da = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True,  serialize=False, verbose_name='Código')
    ativo = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='ATIVO')
    data_cadastro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Data cadastro')
    data_alteracao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Data alteração')
    servidor = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Servidor')
    total = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total')
    atual = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Atual')
    diferenca = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Diferença')
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Usuario',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'agente_da'
        verbose_name_plural = 'agentes_da'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f"{self.id_agentes_da} - {self.servidor} - {self.total} - {self.atual} - {self.diferenca} - {self.ativo} - {self.usuario}"
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usuario = self.usuario if len(User.objects.filter(username=self.usuario)[0]) != 0 else User.objects.filter(username='robo')[0] 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

O campo "self.usuario" é uma foreign key do model "usuario".

No meu script onde chamo o model "AgenteDa", passo as informações:

```
agente_da = AgenteDa()
agente_da.ativo = True
agente_da.servidor = "Cleber"
agente_da.atual = 37
agente_da.total = 47
agente_da.diferenca = 23
# agente_da.usuario = User.objects.filter(username='robo')[0]
agente_da.save()
```

Nesse caso estou omitindo o campo "agente_da.usuario" de propósito para cair na validação dentro do model "AgenteDa".
É aqui estou com problemas.

Ao fazer isso, ou seja, não passar informação no campo "agente_da.usuario", quando chega na função **save()** do  model gera erro:

**raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
db.models.agente_da_models.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: AgenteDa has no usuario**

Minha pergunta é:
Como faço para validar **"self.usuario"** dentro do model se está recebendo informação ou não?

Quando faço simplesmente assim:

```
if not self.usuario:
    self.usuario = User.objects.filter(username='robo')[0]
```

Recebo erro assim:
**ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<User: robo>]>": "AgenteDa.usuario" must be a "User" instance.**
ou assim:
**db.models.agente_da_models.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: AgenteDa has no usuario.**

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar registrado o modo como consegui resoler, caso alguém tenha esse problema, ou tenha uma solução melhor.

Finalmente consegui resolver fazendo da seguinte forma:
Como não achei uma forma melhor de ler, ou validar o **'self.usuario'**, descobri um Exception para faqzer esse tratamento:

```
try:
            self.usuario = self.usuario
        except (User.MultipleObjectsReturned, User.DoesNotExist):
            self.usuario = User.objects.filter(username="robo")[0]
```

Desse modo mesmo não tendo informação em **'self.usuario'** consigo tratar o Exception gerado.

Tal solução foi possível com essa referencia:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877340/typeerror-doesnotexist-object-is-not-callable

Caso alguém tenha uma solução melhor, será bem vinda.